# Is it possible to make a chroot -bind with debian under mac os x lion?

Tags: debian, osx, chroot

Within Linux (e.g. Ubuntu), it is possible to mount partitions like `/home`, `/etc`, `/lib` from another Linux machine and bind them to `/proc` `/sys` `/tmp` to the host's to actually take control of the mounted non-booted linux system. i.e using the other one as host.

This can be done with `mount -bind bla bla bla`
and the `chroot` command.

The question is, is it possible to do this within Mac OS X as host?

With this we could forget fink and macports and have a completely debian distro working on Mac OS X.

Any ideas to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

No, OSX is BSD (Unix) based, obviously Debian is Linux. The kernels are not drop in replacements for each other.

There is an alternative to Fink and Macports, it is called [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). You could also run a Virtual Machine under VirtualBox (free) or VMware/Parallels (Not free).

Comment: But what about Debian ported to BSD?  http://www.debian.org/ports/netbsd/   http://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/

Comment: @Juan seems 1000x more convoluted than just using macports.